# How to make dropdown list and link data on the row to specific cell on different sheet

Tags: drop-down-menu, label

I have a question about making a label by using dropdown list getting multiple column data from other sheet to the specific cell.

my sample file is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16K3o48vBEE2nLyYViT0WQd0Tjxhcsl8h1K4J-_4Abgs/edit#gid=0)

From the "How to" file I have two sheets, sheet 1 is for making dropdown list to get data from sheet2. but i only make dropdown list from data from sheet2!A2:A (dont know how to get all data from multiple columns).What i want is all data from the row of Code (that i select from dropdown list) to show in the specific cell in the box next to it.

Could you please suggest me what formula will work on this case, or what function I should to try. Thanks in advance.
Shawn Penn

Comment: Please clarify your question as it is a little unclear at the moment.

Comment: Ok, thanks for replying. now i've changed the example file. the question is how to choose from dropdown list on sheet1 then get all data in the row from sheet2 appearing on the box next to the dropdown-menu on sheet1.